# Cannot read property of undefined Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I am trying to do a simple import but I am getting a massive [stack trace](http://pastebin.com/GZpzsALv) issue.

I have tried searching everywhere for issues related to this but to me, the stack trace doesn't provide much information.

EDIT: I have tried setting it a variable that isn't fetched from Firebase and it works fine. I guess the question now is how do I handle this information from Firebase so that it loads when it is ready.

Here are the relevant files:

main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

player.services.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Player} from "../classes/player";


@Injectable()
export class PlayerService {

    player: Player;

    getPlayer()
    {
        return Promise.resolve(this.player);
    }

    createPlayer(uid: string, name: string, firebaseRef: Firebase)
    {
        this.player = {
            'uid': uid,
            'name': name,
            'level': 1,
            'maxHealth': 100,
            'health': 100,
            'maxEnergy': 50,
            'energy': 50,
            'fun': 1,
            'skill': 1,
            'knowledge': 1
        }

        firebaseRef.child('players').child(uid).set(this.player);
    }

    setPlayer(player: Player)
    {
        this.player = player;
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { PlayerDetailComponent } from './components/player-detail.component';
import {PlayerService} from "./services/player.service";
import {FirebaseEventPipe} from "./firebasepipe";
import {Player} from "./classes/player";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: 'app/views/app.component.html',
    directives: [PlayerDetailComponent],
    providers: [PlayerService],
    pipes: [FirebaseEventPipe]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    title = "title";

    authData: any;

    private firebaseUrl: string;
    private firebaseRef: Firebase;

    private loggedIn = false;
    player: Player;

    constructor(private playerService: PlayerService) {
        this.firebaseUrl = "https://!.firebaseio.com/";
        this.firebaseRef = new Firebase(this.firebaseUrl);
        this.firebaseRef.onAuth((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.authData = user;
                this.loggedIn = true;
            }
        });
    }

    getPlayer() {
        this.firebaseRef.once("value", (dataSnapshot) => {
            if (dataSnapshot.child('players').child(this.authData.uid).exists()) {
                this.firebaseRef.child('players').child(this.authData.uid).once("value", (data) => {
                    this.player = data.val();
                    this.playerService.setPlayer(this.player);
                    console.log(this.player);
                });
            } else {
                this.playerService.createPlayer(this.authData.uid, this.getName(this.authData), this.firebaseRef);
                this.playerService.getPlayer().then(player => this.player);
                console.log(this.player);
            }

        });




    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getPlayer();
    }

    authWithGithub() {
        this.firebaseRef.authWithOAuthPopup("github", (error) =>
        {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }

    authWithGoogle() {
        this.firebaseRef.authWithOAuthPopup("google",(error) =>
        {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

    }

    getName(authData: any) {
        switch (authData.provider) {
            case 'github':
                return authData.github.displayName;
            case 'google':
                return authData.google.displayName;
        }
    }
}
```

player-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Player } from '../classes/player';


@Component({
    selector: "player-details",
    templateUrl: "app/views/player-detail.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['app/style/player-detail.component.css'],
})

export class PlayerDetailComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() player: Player;

    ngOnInit() { console.log(this.player)}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="navbar-link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron" [hidden]="loggedIn">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Angular Attack Project</h1>
        <p>This is a project for the <a href="https://www.angularattack.com/">Angular Attack 2016</a> hackathon. This is a small project where set goals
            in order to gain experience as a player and person. In order to begin, please register with on of the following services</p>
        <button class="btn btn-social btn-github" (click)="authWithGithub()"><span class="fa fa-github"></span>Sign Up With Github </button>
        <button class="btn btn-social btn-google" (click)="authWithGoogle()"><span class="fa fa-google"></span>Sign Up With Github </button>
    </div>
</div>


<player-details [player]="player" [hidden]="!loggedIn"></player-details>
```

player-detail.component.html

```
<div id="player" class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="player-stats" class="panel-body">
        <img id="player-image" class="img-responsive" src="../app/assets/images/boy.png"/>
        <div class="health-bars">
            <div class="health-bar">HEALTH:<br/><progress value="{{ player.health }}" max="{{ player.maxHealth }}"></progress></div>
            <div class="energy-bar">ENERGY:<br/><progress value="{{ player.energy }}" max="{{ player.maxEnergy }}"></progress></div>
            <div class="player-attributes"><span class="fa fa-futbol-o player-attr fun">: {{ player.fun }} </span><span class="fa fa-cubes player-attr skill">: {{ player.skill }}</span> <span class="fa fa-graduation-cap player-attr knowledge">: {{ player.knowledge }}</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the stack trace is indicating that the error is coming from the player-detail.component.html... can you include that code please?

Comment: Sorry, thought I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The player variable was undefined when the `PlayerDetailComponent` was loaded therefore there was no such object as player.

To fix this, `OnChanges` can be implemented like this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';
import { Player } from '../classes/player';
import {HealthBarComponent} from "./health-bar.component";
import {ChecklistComponent} from "./checklist.component";


@Component({
    selector: "player-details",
    templateUrl: "app/views/player-detail.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['app/style/player-detail.component.css'],
    directives: [HealthBarComponent, ChecklistComponent],
})

export class PlayerDetailComponent implements OnChanges{

    @Input()
    player: Player;

    ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    }


}
```

and then we can add `*nfIf="player"` within the template to ensure that the player object isn't blank before loading the element.

Answer (score 1):

In your service you don't have to return with the promise. You can use a getter

```
private player: Player;

get CurrentPlayer()
{
    return this.player;
}
```

Then in your component:

```
    getPlayer() {

            this.firebaseRef.once("value", (dataSnapshot) => {
                if (dataSnapshot.child('players').child(this.authData.uid).exists()) {
                    this.firebaseRef.child('players').child(this.authData.uid).once("value", (data) => {
this.playerService.setPlayer(this.player);                        
                        console.log(this.player);
                    });
                } else {
                    this.playerService.createPlayer(this.authData.uid, this.getName(this.authData), this.firebaseRef);
                    console.log(this.player);
                }

            });

       ngOnInit() {
    this.player = this.playerService.CurrentPlayer();
            this.getPlayer();
        }
```

If you setup the reference first, it should automatically update. You can also throw an *ngIf player-details component definition in the DOM and only show it once the player object isn't undefined.

**Edit**
Just saw someone else posted about *ngIf prior to me, so if that is the solution, please mark theirs.

Comment: From my understanding, which is very limited, it's just a way of handling an asynchronous call. It's definitely not needed in my application and I have changed it back to `this.player = this.playerService.getPlayer()` and the error still persists.

Comment: What I was suggesting you do, is this... `this.playerService.getPlayer().then((player) => {this.player = player;});`

Comment: That makes more sense but I think the method I was using worked as I was still getting values in my console.log. Implementing your method doesn't seem to solve the issue either.

Comment: Is your else block being hit in your case? If not, then `this.player = data.val();` may not be working how you expect it to. The stack trace indicates that the player object is not defined, so it has to be something to do with how you are setting that.

Comment: Yeah the else block is being hit. I think it's more of an issue with loading the data into the Input. I'm fetching something from Firebase but the template is created before that data loads so the Input variable is blank. That's at least what I think is happening.

Comment: Your player variable is definitely undefined to begin with. The fact that it is getting set in an asynchronous call via Promise.resolve may not be triggering the data binding. I'll edit my answer to have you try something...

Comment: I appreciate all the help but unfortunately, that doesn't appear to solve my issue either.

Comment: I just noticed there is a firebase call wrapping the code I've been referencing which is probably asynchronous. So, I would try one last thing... which I'll update in my answer... If that doesn't work, then I have failed you haha